# Null Coalescing Operator in C# to operate on the non-null value

Tags: string-formatting, c#-6.0, null-coalescing-operator

I have a string which I want to modify if it is not null.

With the null coalescing operator it is easy to return a value when the string is null.

How can I modify the string elegantly when the string is not null?

For example, this is what the NCO is good for - elegant code when a value is null:

```
var nice = mightBeNull ?? "is nice";
```

If I want to modify the string `mightBeNull`, when it is not null, in as concise and elegant manner, what do I do? The best I have so far is:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string ValidateNicely(this string mightBeNice)
    {
        return Regex.Replace((mightBeNice ?? string.Empty).Trim(), @"\s+", " ").ToUpper();
    }
}
var nice = mightBeNice?.ValidateNicely();
```

Creating a very general extension method seems like overkill as it could easily be used in the wrong way.

Comment: Imagine what you're asking for existed. What would your code look like?

Comment: Perhaps a negated null coalescing operator...  mightBeNice !? Regex.Replace(mightBeNice.Trim(), ......

Comment: What's that got to do with the question in my post? My posted question is not asking for a change to the C# language - this is the wrong place for that - it is asking what, currently, is the most elegant way to express a particular piece of logic.

Comment: Strings can't be modified. All operations create *new* strings. Using `??` in this case not only makes the code *harder* to read, it wastes resources doing nothing. `?:` would be more appropriate, `return (mightBeNice==null)?"":Regex.Replace(mightBeNice).Trim(), @"\s+", " ").ToUpper();`. *Two* separate lines would be even cleaner. Finally, regular expressions are thread-safe which means the regex object could be stored in a static field, reducing the code *and* avoiding recompilations each time `Regex.Replace` is called.